# getChild method in a module doesn't seem to refer to a child(?)

Tags: layout, blocks

I am using the Meanbee [Infinite Scroll](https://www.meanbee.com/magento-extensions/infinite-scroll.html) module in my project. I have it working for normal category product listings. But now I'm attempting to have it activate on my custom made module.

However I am stumped over line `68` in `Script.php`:

```
 66       return (
 67           $block !== false &&
 68           $block->getChild('toolbar') !== false && // <-- This line
 69           $this->_getPagerBlock() !== false &&
 70           $this->_getPagerBlock()->getCollection()
 71       );
```

There is no xml element that has the name of `toolbar`. Even in the normal category xml that is working. So what is `"toolbar"` refering to?

A `var_dump($block->getChild('toolbar'));` returns false on my page but not on the normal category product listing page.

My XML is as follows (for clarity):

```
        <block type="mynamespace/mymodule" name="mymodule.view" template="mynamespace/mymodule/view.phtml">
            <block type="catalog/product_list" name="product_list" template="toxicfox/giftfinder/list.phtml">
                <block type="catalog/product_list_toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar" template="catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml">
                    <block type="page/html_pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager"/>
                </block>
                <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>empty</layout><count>6</count></action>
                <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>one_column</layout><count>5</count></action>
                <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>two_columns_left</layout><count>4</count></action>
                <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>two_columns_right</layout><count>4</count></action>
                <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>three_columns</layout><count>3</count></action>
                <action method="setToolbarBlockName"><name>product_list_toolbar</name></action>
            </block>
        </block>
```

And the core XML (which works with the Infinite Scroll module) is:

```
        <block type="catalog/category_view" name="category.products" template="catalog/category/view.phtml">
            <block type="catalog/product_list" name="product_list" template="catalog/product/list.phtml">
                <block type="catalog/product_list_toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar" template="catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml">
                    <block type="page/html_pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager"/>
                </block>
                <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>empty</layout><count>6</count></action>
                <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>one_column</layout><count>5</count></action>
                <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>two_columns_left</layout><count>4</count></action>
                <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>two_columns_right</layout><count>4</count></action>
                <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>three_columns</layout><count>3</count></action>
                <action method="setToolbarBlockName"><name>product_list_toolbar</name></action>
            </block>
        </block>
```

As you can see, neither block of XML has any element with an attribute `name` of `"toolbar"`. The only difference is line `1`.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

This is easy, the toolbar block is generated in the block class, e.g. here:

```
\Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List::getToolbarBlock
/**
 * Retrieve Toolbar block
 *
 * @return Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List_Toolbar
 */
public function getToolbarBlock()
{
    if ($blockName = $this->getToolbarBlockName()) {
        if ($block = $this->getLayout()->getBlock($blockName)) {
            return $block;
        }
    }
    $block = $this->getLayout()->createBlock($this->_defaultToolbarBlock, microtime());
    return $block;
}
```

And is set here:

```
/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/List.php:160
$this->setChild('toolbar', $toolbar);
```

Method:

```
\Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List::_beforeToHtml
protected function _beforeToHtml()
{
    $toolbar = $this->getToolbarBlock();

    // doing a lot of things with the toolbar, setting limit, ordering, direction, etc.

    $this->setChild('toolbar', $toolbar);
    Mage::dispatchEvent('catalog_block_product_list_collection', array(
        'collection' => $this->_getProductCollection()
    ));

    $this->_getProductCollection()->load();

    return parent::_beforeToHtml();
}
```

Comment: Hi Fabian, Is there to remove the toolbar via layout xml? Say in a Category's Custom Design?

Comment: No I don't think this is possible, because layout is already read and processed, when the toolbar block is generated, but you can try `<remove name="toolbar" />`

Comment: Yeah, the remove tag doesn't work (first thing I tried). Thanks, though!